# Parsing a config file inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, config

I am trying to parse an ini file inside a shell script.

name.conf file:

```
Name1 : abc
Name2 : xyz
```

I could parse the values by the command

```
name1=$(awk '/^Name1/{print $3}' name.conf)
name2=$(awk '/^Name2/{print $3}' name.conf)
```

I wanted to know if there was some way by which I could group the contents of my config and parse it

name.conf file:

```
[Names]
abc
xyz
[Values]
blah
blahh
```

I just need the values in a shell array say names and print them like this

```
for var in $names
do
   echo $var
done
for var in $values
do
   echo $var
done
```

Comment: What is the output you expect. Please provide sample output and how it is coming. In you second name.conf file, the `[Names]` are understood but how is the `[Values]` coming in the output?

Comment: I expect to get the values 'abc' and 'xyz' , in two variables inside a shell script, as in my first script.

Comment: why not just use `NAME=VALUE` format for your config and then just `source` it?

Comment: then what are `blah` and `blahh`?

Comment: It contains more than 10 names and values, so that would be hard to declare a new variable for each of them.I just showed two varables as an example.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish,those could be any values.

Comment: So, does the configuration file have colons separating the name from the value as shown in the first fragment, or does it not as shown in the second fragment.  Be self-consistent.  Show an example small input (the 6 lines is good) and the output you want from it.  Also, if the colons are present, are they required to be separated from the name and value by spaces?  Or can the colons touch either the name or the value or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier than that. Just put all vars in a file ("vars", for instance), in "name = value" format:

```
name1 = abc
name2 = xyz
```

Then in your main script, use "source" to load it:

```
#!/bin/bash
source vars
```

Or using period also works:

```
#!/bin/bash
. vars
```

Although that will only work if you run the script where the vars file is. Nagios use this approach to be able to run the script anywhere in the system:

```
#! /bin/bash
PROGNAME=`basename $0`
PROGPATH=`echo $0 | sed -e 's,[\\/][^\\/][^\\/]*$,,'`
. $PROGPATH/vars

echo $name1
```

The output for that should be 'abc'

Comment: What if say i have to add a few more names to the conf file?

Comment: I will have to edit my shell script to accomodate the new values

Comment: Nope, you won't. Next time you run the script, the "vars" file will be re-read and the new values will be there for you.

Comment: How can I access a particular value say value of name2..Is it like `$vars[name2]` ?

Comment: It's just the name of the var you put in the "vars" file. In my example, you'll have var $name1 with value 'abc' and var $name2 with value 'xyz'.

Comment: Ok..Thanks.I'll try that

Comment: It didn't work.I'm getting errors -                                                              : **name.conf:line 3: abc: command not found
name.conf: line 4: xyz: command not found
name.conf: line 5: qwe: command not found**

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning your vars in the form "var = value"??? Looks like you are putting "xyz" by itself in a single line. Share the code.

Comment: It was due to a space , var=value instead of var = value solved it